API for certutil
When I import a renewed certificate in any store the private key is not always assigned.
For that e.g.,
certutil.exe -repairstore my <CertSerial>

does the trick. It just assigns the previously stored private key.
Is there an API preferably for C# to achieve the same?
Using
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName    = "certutil.exe",
    Arguments   = "-repairstore my 12345",
};

Process.Start(psi);

works but this is just a dumb workaround.
